# Python: Trying to scan for active bluetooth devices

Tags: python, bluetooth

I found online multiple sources that said that discover_devices scans for active bluetooth devices, but for me it was printing all the bluetooth devices that remembered on my computer. Is there something wrong with my code/settings?

`

```
import bluetooth

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
print(nearby_devices)

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    print('\nname = ', name, "\naddress = ", addr)
```

`

Comment: This is not a Python issue *per se*. You should address this question to the author of pybluez